# Creating graphs in python using numbers from a list

Tags: python, list, graph

```
LI=[]
LE=[]
LG=[]
LIR=[]
ImE=0.1
ImI=0.01
ImG=1000
PE=5000000
PI=10000000
PG=3000000
PIr=2000000
t=10

for i in range(t):
    PE=PE+ImI-ImE*PE
    PI=PI+PE*ImE+ImG-ImI*PI
    PG=PG-ImG
    PIr=PIr
    LE.append(PE)
    LI.append(PI)
    LG.append(PG)
    LIR.append(PIr)
```

Using the numbers added to the lists how could I create a graph with a line representing each list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have matplotlib installed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(t), LE, label='E')
```